# Undefined para o corpo de uma requisição

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, response, knex.js

Estou tentando criar uma funcionalidade de **Postagens** em Node, em que uma postagem terá os seguintes campos : **category**, **title** e **description**. A entidade responsável por fazer esta funcionalidade se chama **posts**, que está configurada da seguinte maneira :

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('posts', function(table){
        //chave primária que se auto incrementa a cada post
        table.increments()

        table.string('category').notNullable()
        table.string('title').notNullable()
        table.string('description').notNullable()

    })
};
```

Feito isto criei uma rota para realizar esta funcionalidade, em que se encontra da seguinte maneira :

```
routes.post('/postagens', (request, response) => {

    const data = request.body
    console.log(data)

    return response.json()
})
```

Para testar, enviei uma requisição utilizando o método **POST** com o conteúdo sendo enviado em formato **JSON** da seguinte maneira :

```
{
    "category": "stackoverflow",
    "title": "erro à ser corrigido",
    "description": "retorno undefined"
}
```

Isto posto, recebo o seguinte conteúdo em `console.log(data)` : **undefined**.

Como posso fazer para que data receba o corpo desta minha requisição ?

Comment: Está usando `express`?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. estou sim utilizando o express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Você pode fazer o seguinte código em seu arquivo principal (normalmente o `index.js`):

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
```

Isso permite que o servidor entenda requisições com o corpo em `json`

Comment: Opa, coloquei isto e continuo retornando undefined. Segue o meu arquivo index.js no momento : const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes')
const app = express()

app.use(routes)
app.use(express.json())
app.listen(3333)

Comment: @GabrielRibeiroCarneiro, então, coloca o `app.use(express.json())` antes de `app.use(routes)`

Comment: FUNCIONOU! Muito obrigado